# Python script is printing \u2013

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My python script is printing \u2013 when I read line from text file.
Please help on this. how to avoid.Thanks in advance

```
My text in file:

 "Re-integratieassistent – modelnummer rea 202"

Result:

u'\ufeffRe-integratieassistent \u2013 modelnummer rea 202'
```

script

```
f = codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding ='utf-8')

print repr(f.readline())
#line = f.readline()

#print "Read Line: %s" % (line)


f.close()
```

Comment: That's the Unicode codepoint for a dash. Probably happening because you're using `repr`... Just do `print f.readline()`.

Answer (score 0):

> `print repr(f.readline())`

This prints a **representation** of the string, not the string itself.

Python will thus escape the string. You should just `print(f.readline())` if you want to print the string as is.

Answer (score 0):

`\u2013` is the symbol `–`. Since you are printing using `repr` it will be shown as `\u2013`. try printing without it:

```
print  f.readline()
```

You have the BOM character `\ufeff`, better use the encoding `utf-8-sig` to open the file.

Comment: it is giving below error UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position
 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Testuser use the encoding `utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8`

Comment: Now I am getting this error UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position
 23: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Testuser try `codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding ='utf-8', errors = "ignore")`

Comment: Now previous error is showing     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in positio
 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: and `codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding ='utf-8-sig', errors = "ignore")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95702/discussion-between-testuser-and-bigother).